# "Когда" и "Если" в начале предложения: их взаимозаменяемость

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

Ниже приведены четыре варианта одной и той же инструкции из моего документа об именовании файлов.

Чтобы сравнивать их было легче, я оформил их в виде моноширинного текста и пронумеровал.

> ```
> 1. Артикли опускай. Когда они не могут быть опущены,
> артикль в начале имени файла перемещай в его конец.
> ```
>
> ```
> 2. Артикли опускай. Если они не могут быть опущены,
> артикль в начале имени файла перемещай в его конец.
> ```
>
> ```
> 3. Артикли опускай. Когда они не могут быть опущены,
> артикль в начале имени файла перемести в его конец.
> ```
>
> ```
> 4. Артикли опускай. Если они не могут быть опущены,
> артикль в начале имени файла перемести в его конец.
> ```
>
> - The Lord of the Rings → `lord_of_rings`
> - The Lord of the Rings → `lord_of_the_rings_the`

Их отличия, на которые следует обратить внимание:

- **В первой строке:** Когда / Если
- **Во второй строке:** Перемещай / Перемести

Прав ли я, что *когда* следует сочетать лишь с *перемещай*, а *если* - лишь с *перемести* (и таким образом правильными являются только первый и четвертый варианты)? Это первый из моих вопросов.

Перейду ко второму. Еще одна цитата из того же документа:

> Когда они используются в качестве дополнений (= являются необязательными), опускай относительные местоимения which, who, whom, whose и that.
>
> - The woman [that] the man loved was living in New York.
> - The woman that spoke at the meeting was very knowledgeable.

По моим ощущениям, замена слова *Когда* на *Если* в этом примере выглядит неуместно. Так ли это, и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно обратили внимание на то, что "**когда**" и "**если**" *не всегда взаимозаменяемы*. Действительно, в английском варианте тому и другому *может* соответствовать **when**. Возьмём для примера название фильма *When You Are Strange* (строка из песни The Doors 'People Are Strange'). Буквальным переводом 'when' на русский было бы "когда", но это сделало бы русский текст не вполне естественным ("Когда ты странный"): получилось бы, что речь идёт о способности человека быть *странным* (или "не таким, как все") *время от времени* (когда...), в то время как говорится о *постоянном* свойстве характера ("если вы странный" - не такой, как все и т. п.).

Так и в ваших примерах: случаю "**когда**" лучше соответствует "**перемещай/опускай(-те)**", а случаю "**если**" - "**перемести/опусти(-те)**". Это происходит потому, что в имеющемся контексте инструкций "**когда**" воспринимается как "*в **тех** случаях когда...*" - указание на *множественность* случаев, которые ожидаются; "**если**" в том же контексте воспринимается как *отдельный* (каждый отдельно рассматриваемый = *в **том** случае, если...*) случай (он либо сам по себе, либо **один** из множественных "когда").

Таким образом, "**когда**" в вашем случае тяготеет к *множественности* (*всякий раз **перемещай***), а "**если**" - к *единственности* (*в этом случае **перемести***).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. Мне показалось, что второй вопрос вам отвечать было лень, но ничего страшного: похоже, на него я вопрос нашел сам, и вероятно благодаря вашему ответу. Замена слова "когда" на "если" во фрагменте "Когда они используются в качестве дополнений" приведёт к тому, что текст будет читаться словно бы which, who, whom, whose и that могут использоваться все одновременно. А вероятность такого крайне мала и мы, конечно же, рассматриваем этот фрагмент как описание 5 разных случаев, имея тем самым множественность, а значит должны использовать "когда", а не "если".

Answer (score 1):

«Перемещай» — несовершенный вид глагола, «перемести» — совершенный.

Несовершенный вид глагола может означать:

> 2. повто­ря­ю­ще­е­ся или мно­го­крат­ное действие:
>
> [[russkiiyazyk.ru](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/nesovershennogo-vida.html)]

«Перемести» — единоразово. «Перемещай» — повто­ря­ю­ще­е­ся или мно­го­крат­ное действие.

Не зависимо от того «если» или «когда», лучше «перемещай», потому что имеется в виду, каждый раз, когда случается такая ситуация, делай так.

Кроме того, «перемещай» — звучит более вежливо, а «перемести» как приказ.

Если вы приглашаете кого-то на прогулку, вы скажите: «Выходи на улицу», а не «Выйди на улицу», потому что «Выйди на улицу» звучит как приказ.

> Например, А. Мазон в 1914 г. высказал мнение о том, что «императив
> несовершенного вида является менее категоричным и менее авторитарным,
> чем императив совершенного вида» (Mazon 1914, 66).
>
> [[ROSANNA BENACCHIOКОНКУРЕНЦИЯ ВИДОВ, ВЕЖЛИВОСТЬ И ЭТИКЕТ ВРУССКОМ
> ИМПЕРАТИВЕ с сайта researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241052109_Konkurencija_vidov_vezlivost%E2%80%99_i_etiket_v_russkom_imperative_Aspectual_Competition_Politeness_and_Etiquette_in_the_Russian_Imperative#read)]

---

На мой взгляд, союз «если» более универсальный и им можно заменить «когда».

> Е́сли. Вероятно, заимствовано из польского, где jesli — «если», где
> это слово является сращением est (форма глагола от bye — «быть») с
> частицей li: est-li. Русский язык заимствовал это слово в виде
> есть-ли, а со временем оно трансформировалось до сегодняшнего если.
>
> [Этимологическом словарь Крылова Г. А.]

То есть «если» – это «есть-ли», есть ли условие.

Союз «когда» имеет оттенок временно́го условия.

Я думаю тут подходит определение:

> в) для обозначения повторяемости действия (чаще со словами „каждый
> раз“, „всякий раз“, „всегда“ в главном предложении).
>
> ```
> Каждый раз, когда я приходил, Олеся встречала меня с своим привычным сдержанным достоинством. Куприн, Олеся. Штыковой бой был упорный, как всегда, когда дрались русские. Сергеев-Ценский, Севастопольская страда;
> ```
>
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

В данном случае «когда» лучше «если», потому что «когда» имеет значение «каждый раз, когда такая ситуация возникает», и с ним хорошо сочетается «перемещай», тоже имеющее значение многократности. Кроме того «перемещай» – более вежливо, не создаёт ощущение приказа.

---

И ещё:

*«Артикли опускай. Когда они не могут быть опущены,
артикль в начале имени файла перемещай в его конец».*

У вас в одном предложении сначала множественное число об артиклях, а потом единственное: «они» [артикли], «артикль» [он].

Местоимение «его» вызывает путаницу в восприятии, чей «его конец»? Конец имени? Конец файла? Конец артикля?

Лучше:

*Когда артикль стоит в начале имени файла и не может быть опущен,
перемещай его в конец имени файла.*

А ещё лучше вообще убрать приказ:

*Когда артикль стоит в начале имени файла и не может быть опущен,
его следует переместить в конец имени файла.*

---

*«Когда они используются в качестве дополнений (= являются необязательными)…»*

Тут под дополнениями понимается, по-моему, член предложения «дополнение», а не что-то необязательное.

---

В английском языке тоже есть два союза: «if» и «when». Понятно, что это разные языка, но можно попробовать найти аналогии.

> **When** and **if** are easily confused; sometimes they are interchangeable
> but very often they have different meanings. Both words can talk about
> repeated actions, and both can express a condition. The key difference
> is that when refers to a fairly certain conditions in the future,
> while if introduces something uncertain, unlikely or hypothetical.
>
> «Когда» и «если» легко спутать; иногда они взаимозаменяемы, но очень
> часто имеют разное значение. Оба слова могут сообщать о повторяющихся
> действиях, и оба могут выражать состояние. **Ключевое отличие состоит в
> том, что «когда» относится к довольно определенным условиям в будущем,
> а «если» вводит что-то неувернное, маловероятное или
> гипотетическое.**
>
> [[english.lingolia.com](https://english.lingolia.com/en/vocabulary/confusing-words/when-if)]

В русском языке похожая ситуация:

*Когда артикль стоит в начале имени файла и не может быть опущен,
его следует переместить в конец имени файла.*

Говорится про ситуации, которые могут возникнуть в будущем, и как в случае возникновения этих ситуаций можно поступить.

С того же сайта [english.lingolia.com](https://english.lingolia.com/en/vocabulary/confusing-words/when-if):

> Use if for an action or event in the future that is uncertain.
>
> Example: If it’s sunny, Jenny will relax on the beach.
>
> if = in case of or in the event that
>
> Используйте «if» для действия или события в будущем, по которым нет
> уверенности.
>
> Пример:
>
> *Если погода будет солнечной, Дженни будет отдыхать на пляже.*
>
> if = в случае или при возникновении события

Таким образом, «если» может иметь оттенок неуверенности: если так, то так, а если так, то так.

«Когда» же звучит более утвердительно:

*Когда погода будет солнечной, Дженни будет отдыхать на пляже.*

---

Но это больше мои мысли. Вы принимайте решение сами.

---

*«Когда они используются в качестве дополнений (= являются необязательными), опускай относительные местоимения which, who, whom, whose и that.*

Я бы изменил так:
*«Когда относительные местоимения: which, who, whom, whose и that — используются в качестве дополнений, их следует опускать»*.

Comment: Eagle, прошу прощения что не откомментировал столь подробый ответ. Очень много полезного, благодарю. Отдельное спасибо за ссылку на научную работу об императиве. А ваш рейтинг, надеюсь, через 2 дня восстановится. Принятый ответ, вероятно, позже изменю на ваш.